# Sharepoint Feature Batch Deployment Script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment

Does anyone have a batch file we can use to deploy solutions and and activate features into sharepoint.

The batch file should contain pause to allow features to activate and only then move on to the next feature.

Also instructions to run this from a command line so this can be used later in automation software

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010, I recommend a PowerShell script instead of a batch file. An example that appears to be working can be found here:
[SharePoint 2010: PowerShell to Wait for WSP Solution Deployment Timer Job to Complete](http://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/sharepoint-2010-powershell-to-wait-for-wsp-solution-deployment-timer-job-to-complete/)